# Scapy Sniff() not capturing any packets without filters (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, scapy

i'm new to using Scapy (and Python), but have been running into some problems when trying to use sniff(). No packets are captured whatsoever unless I add a filter.

E.g. sniff() returns nothing, where sniff(filter="tcp") will return packets.
Certain filters don't seem to work properly either, like "port 80", for http packets.

I've tried specifying the iface, which doesn't seem to change anything either. Wireshark seems to capture everything just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!